# How to remove img tag in php using if else statement?

Tags: php, html

How do I remove an `<img>` tag in the HTML if the `<img>` cannot be loaded from the server? I want to do this so that the "error image icon" won't show and will just be treated as a blank `<div>`.

```
<? if(file_exists($gallery_file_path)) {
    $gallery_file = $gallery_url.$gallery_id ."/".file_name($gallery_file)."_thumb.".file_ext($gallery_file);
?>
    <img class="main-img" src="<?=$gallery_file?>"> <!-- IMAGE here -->             
<? } ?>
```

Comment: you also have to check if `$gallery_file` is existing or not

Comment: Hey @billybobjones .. accept my answer if it somehow helped you. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the exact file name:

```
<?php 

$file_image_name = file_name($gallery_file)."_thumb.".file_ext($gallery_file);
if(file_exists($gallery_file_path.'/'.$file_image-name))
{

?>

<img class="main-img" src="<?=$file_image_name?>"> <!-- IMAGE here -->  

<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to remove the `<img>` tag just check if file exist and it is a file not a dir put the `<img>` tag and else put `<div>` tag:

```
<?php
    if(file_exists($gallery_file_path) && is_file($gallery_file_path)){
        $gallery_file = $gallery_url.$gallery_id."/".file_name($gallery_file)."_thumb.".file_ext($gallery_file);
        ?><img class="main-img" src="<?=$gallery_file?>"> <!-- IMAGE here -->
<?php
    }else{
        ?><div></div><?php
    }
?>
```